# how to create custom theme in liferay using bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, liferay

I have extended _unstyled theme in liferay and used `bootstrap3 css` for control panel styling, but I have issue with navigation bar at site page management.
It is not displaying though the data is loaded in dom.

Comment: If you're in Liferay 6.2, embedding bootstrap 3 will be really hard. Liferay 7 (scheduled to be out soon) will have it embedded. For 6.1 I've heard that people have achieved it. If you succeed implementing bootstrap3 on Liferay6.2 and publish your findings or your theme, you'll be everyone's hero. Or, to say it differently: Just accept that Liferay 6.2 runs on bootstrap 2.3 and concentrate on solving other problems. In a related note, "I have extended..." is not quite enough information to give you hints on what you should do differently anyways.

Comment: I have implemented in Liferay 6.1 Bootstrap 3, without problems. And Liferay 6.2 also =). the response I show an example and as I did. @OlafKock

Comment: Hello @prasad8mhatre I taught a link to do so

Comment: I would like to hear your opinion @OlafKock

Comment: Are you using any Liferay-out-of-the-box portlets other than "WebContent Display" with that theme? E.g. some with an application interface, like Document Library, or less complex ones? How do they look like? It might be "good enough" for a simple usecase, but I'm sceptical if there's a full solution. If it is a full solution, make it a deployable theme and publish on Liferay's marketplace - and you'll be famous.

Answer (score 0):

I commented. I am currently doing the layout of a university in Spain using Liferay 6.2 and Bootstrap 3.

I had to change some CSS imcompatibilidades but otherwise no problems. As if I have a problem is when the .row-fluid I have to use them instead of .row Bootstrap 3 with what generates me a space with .row would not happen.

Everyone told me I was going to have problems because NO, I found the solution.

[LINK WORK LIFERAY WITH BOOTSTRAP 3.3.6 BY MY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35011112/work-with-bootstrap-3-3-6-in-liferay-6-2)

I attached screenshots for you to see how I'm doing:

HOME

[image: HOME]

[image: TEXT]

REGARDS FROM SPAIN!!!!